# PredicateBuilder stripping brackets, breaking nested AND's combined with OR

Tags: c#, .net, linq, predicatebuilder

How can [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) be used to OR together several statements with nested AND's, without stripping brackets?

We are trying to get:

```
(fieldA = X AND fieldB = Y AND fieldC = Z)  or (fieldA = A AND fieldB = B and fieldC = C)
```

But the code below generates (note no brackets, meaning DB query returns wrong data)

```
fieldA = X AND fieldB = Y AND fieldC = Z  or fieldA = A AND fieldB = B and fieldC = C
```

We are building the predicate like this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<MonitoredService>();

foreach (var a in affected)
{
    var a1 = a;
    predicate = predicate.Or(m => m.ItemId == a1.ItemId && m.MinSeverity <= a1.Severity && m.LastUpdatedUtc <= a1.LastModifiedUtc);
}

var monitors = _monitoredServiceRepository.List(predicate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LINQ and SQL Server (and i'm positive that this is also the case for MySQL, Oracle and other DBs), AND operators are evaluated first before OR operator.

So

```
(fieldA = X AND fieldB = Y AND fieldC = Z)  or (fieldA = A AND fieldB = B and fieldC = C)
```

Is same as

```
fieldA = X AND fieldB = Y AND fieldC = Z  or fieldA = A AND fieldB = B and fieldC = C
```